# Adding a something to a wildcard <?> collection in Java

Tags: java

Hello I have this attribute: `private Map<Function<T, Collection<?>>, Template<?>> functionTemplateMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();` To make a map from a function to a template (the template is what I'm coding, if needed I can provide the whole code), and then I have a function called forEach:

```
/**
     * 
     * @param <E> Type of the new objects
     * @param function Lambda that returns a collection of objects of any type 
     * @param string String with gaps
     * @param functions Lambda(s) that accept as argument objects of the same type as the collection returns and will be used to fill the gaps
     */
    public <E extends Comparable<E>> void addForEach(Function<T, Collection<E>> function, String string, Function<E, Object> ...functions) {
        Template<E> temp = new Template<>();
        temp.add(string, functions);
        this.functionTemplateMap.put(function, temp);
        
    }
```

The thing is that the collection that returns the function and the list of functions used as parameters must be of the same type, so I added the `<E>` at the beggining of the function, but since the functionTemplateMap has a `Collection<?>` so that it is more general, when adding it with put it gives me an error saying collection should be `<?>`, but then I can not check if the list of functions is of the same type `<E>`

Comment: If the question is "*How can we make this work?*", then the answer is "*We cannot*". At least not in a type-safe way. We can cast the `Collection<?>` to a `Collection<E>`, but this - as stated above - might break type safety.

Comment: But if I cast `collection<?>` to `<E>` I can't check if the third parameter is also E right? And why can I add a template E to template ? but not collection E to collection ?

Comment: Due to [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), the generic parameters are gone at runtime. So no, checking them is not possible. --- for `Template` it works because `?` is basically `? extends Object`.